# JSTL tag returns null

Tags: forms, jsp, servlets, jstl, hidden-field

In the below code i am iterating a list from the servlet in my JSP page. It works fine, but i need to set the value `${product.reqid}` to the inout field . So that i would post the data with my form .

```
<c:forEach var="product" items="${myArrayList}">
        <tr>      
             <td><c:out value="${product.reqid}"></c:out></td>
             <td><c:out value="${product.proid}"></c:out></td>
             <td><c:out value="${product.proname}"></c:out></td>
             <td><c:out value="${product.username}"></c:out></td>
             <input type ="hidden" name="reqno" value="${product.reqid}">
             <td><input type="submit" value="Approve"></td>
        </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

From the code i tried it prints **NULL** , when i try to print the value in the servlet.
Thanks in advance

Comment: And where's the servlet code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the same technique as you did in the first column of the row

```
<c:forEach var="product" items="${myArrayList}">
        <tr>      
             <td><c:out value="${product.reqid}"></c:out></td>
             <td><c:out value="${product.proid}"></c:out></td>
             <td><c:out value="${product.proname}"></c:out></td>
             <td><c:out value="${product.username}"></c:out></td>
             <input type ="hidden" name="reqno" value="<c:out value="${product.reqid}"/>">
             <td><input type="submit" value="Approve"></td>
        </tr>
</c:forEach>
```